# PowerAutomate/Flow - SharePoint Document Approval by SharePoint Group

Tags: flow, approval-process, power-automate

In SharePoint Designer 2013 workflows we have the option of a `task process` to send tasks to a SharePoint Permission group.

How does one replicate this functionality in Power Automate/Flow? I don't see any options to assign an approval process to a group, only one email at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign approval tasks by following these steps:

- <s>Get all users from an AD group</s>
- Get all users from a SharePoint Group using SharePoint HTTP step: _api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('SiteName Members')/users
- Get all emails from all of these users
- Create a new variable that will contain a concatenated string of all emails with a semicolon as a separator
- In the approval step, assign approval tasks to the variable

Comment: The SharePoint permission groups aren't in AD though?

Comment: sorry, I've missed this point. Updated the answer